# IPathVariableManager.validateValue(URI) returns null

Tags: eclipse-plugin, uri

in the Eclipse plugin I'm working on I have a piece of code which basically looks like this:

```
public static void checkProblemV1() {
   try {
      String path = "C:\\temp";
      org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath value = 
         new org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path(path);
      IPathVariableManager pathManager = 
         ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getPathVariableManager();
      String name = "somename";
      IStatus statusName = pathManager.validateName(name);
      IStatus statusValue = pathManager.validateValue(value);

      if (statusName == null || statusValue == null) {
         System.err.println("checkProblemV1(): statusName is " +
            (statusName == null ? "null" : ("not null: '" + statusName + "'.")));
         System.err.println("checkProblemV1(): statusValue is " +
            (statusValue == null ? "null" : ("not null: '" + statusValue + "'.")));
      }
      else if (statusName.isOK() && statusValue.isOK()) {
         pathManager.setValue(name, value); // setValue is deprecated
         System.out.println("checkProblemV1(): Everything fine");
      }
      else {
         if (!statusName.isOK()) {
            System.err.println("checkProblemV1(): statusName is not OK.");
         }
         if (!statusValue.isOK()) {
            System.err.println("checkProblemV1(): statusValue is not OK.");
         }
      }
   }
   catch (CoreException e) {
      System.err.println("checkProblemV1(): CoreException: " + e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

When the above method is executed, there are no problems, but I get a deprecation warning for setValue() when compiling. It's when I wanted to fix that deprecation warning by replacing the call to setValue() with a call to setURIValue() that I got into trouble. First I had to tweak how that Windows-style path was written to avoid an URISyntaxException but after doing that, setURIValue() returns null and after having a look in the documentation I can't see that it should do that? I guess the URI is invalid after all but don't know how to fix it. Below is a test method in the same style as the one above demonstrating the problem.

```
public static void checkProblemV2() {
   try {
      String path = "C:\\temp";
      // Have to replace \ with /, or we get URISyntaxExeption:
      // checkProblemV2(): URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\temp
      path = path.replace('\\', '/');
      java.net.URI value = new java.net.URI(path);
      IPathVariableManager pathManager = 
         ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getPathVariableManager();
      String name = "somename";
      IStatus statusName = pathManager.validateName(name);
      IStatus statusValue = pathManager.validateValue(value);

      if (statusName == null || statusValue == null) {
         System.err.println("checkProblemV2(): statusName is " +
            (statusName == null ? "null" : ("not null: '" + statusName + "'.")));
         System.err.println("checkProblemV2(): statusValue is " +
            (statusValue == null ? "null" : ("not null: '" + statusValue + "'.")));
      }
      else if (statusName.isOK() && statusValue.isOK()) {
         pathManager.setURIValue(name, value);
         System.out.println("checkProblemV2(): Everything fine");
      }
      else {
         if (!statusName.isOK()) {
            System.err.println("checkProblemV2(): statusName is not OK.");
         }
         if (!statusValue.isOK()) {
            System.err.println("checkProblemV2(): statusValue is not OK.");
         }
      }
   }
   catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      System.err.println("checkProblemV2(): URISyntaxException: " + e.getMessage());
   }
   catch (CoreException e) {
      System.err.println("checkProblemV2(): CoreException: " + e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

When I run the above two methods, I get the following output.

```
checkProblemV1(): Everything fine
checkProblemV2(): statusName is not null: 'Status OK: unknown code=0 OK null'.
checkProblemV2(): statusValue is null
```

Thanks for reading and for any help, it's seriously appreciated!

Comment: I tried the following but I get the same problem:
java.net.URI value = new java.io.File(path).toURI();
(and I skipped the call to path.replace(), just passing the File constructor the path in its original form "C:\\temp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in `org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.PathVariableManager.validateValue(URI)` where it is using other internal methods but returning `null` no matter what else is going on.  Please open a bug with [Eclipse Platform/Resources](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform&component=Resources).

And I agree with your comment, you should use:

```
URI uri = new File("C:\\temp").toURI();
pathManager.setURIValue(theName, uri);
```